# Angular - lists are no refreshing by emit an event by output

Tags: angular, redux

I wrote an app with angular 7 and @angular-redux/store 9.
This app has two lists which contains hero objects. Each object has a boolean marker. The first list shows objects as 'true' marked. The other list shows objects with 'false' marked. If I press an hero object (marked as false) on the first list, the objects was marked as true, removed from the first list and showed on the second list.

I realize this with using a store, which change the flag. The first component receives the list (by select) and give it further to two list components by Input(). The click event used the Output-Parameter.

My Problem: No changes are visible. Thanks for your help.

**Solution:**
I could solve the problem. I used ngDoCheck in parent component
and give it further to the child components.

Answer (score -1):

You are way too complicating here. Solution would be after emitting this change directly in parent to modify list. Then it would affect two child lists. But you are dispatching in service now. 
Also you can try onNgChanges event in child components to catch this changes and update view accordingly.